# Dropdown selected in Laravel and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to retrieve data from database and send it to a form as value, but the problem is it shows the first item of the dropdown list. I want the value that comes from the db, appears as selected.

```
 <!-- Select Service status -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="service_status">Service Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select id="service_status" name="service_status" class="form-control" value="{{ $job_account_detail->service_status }}">
        <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
        <option value="Running">Running</option>
        <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your code to something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="service_status">Service Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select id="service_status" name="service_status" class="form-control">
        <option value="Pending" {{ $job_account_detail->service_status=="Pending" ? "selected" : ''}}>Pending</option>
        <option value="Running" {{ $job_account_detail->service_status=="Running" ? "selected" : ''}}>Running</option>
        <option value="Completed" {{ $job_account_detail->service_status=="Completed" ? "selected" : ''}}>Completed</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you.. it worked.. i have added same type of problem but its with the datepicker.. can i help to solve it?

Comment: You can ask it as a new question.